# How Do I Select All Parents and the Top Previous Child Record Based on Dates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select

I'm using a vendor provided database running on SQL Server 2008. There are two tables that track tests. For every record in Table A there may be zero, one or multiple records in Table B. There can also be multiple tests in Table A for the same user. The relationship is TableA.UserID = TableB.UserID. Tests taken in Table B can occur before or after Table A.

I need to select all of the records in Table A and, if test(s) from Table B have been taken by the same user before the test in Table A, data from Table B but only from the last previous child record. Both tables are structured similarly:

```
**TABLE A**
TestID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
UserID INTEGER,
TestDate DATE,
Score INTEGER

TABLE B
TestID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
UserID INTEGER,
TestDate Date,
Score INTEGER
```

**Sample Data**

```
TABLE A
TestID          UserID          TestDate          Score
1               100             2014-02-15        80
2               101             2014-02-20        100
3               102             2014-02-22        90
4               102             2014-03-10        70

TABLE B
TestID          UserID          TestDate          Score
1000               100             2014-02-01        55
1007               100             2014-02-05        85
1012               100             2014-02-20        95
1034               102             2014-02-12        65
1205               102             2014-03-05        75
1986               101             2014-03-10        45
```

**What I'd like returned would be:**

```
UserID     TestA_ID     TestADate     TestAScore     TestB_ID     TestBDate     TestBScore
100        1            2014-02-15    80             1007         2014-02-05    85
101        2            2014-02-20    100            NULL         NULL          NULL
102        3            2014-02-22    90             1034         2014-02-12    65
102        4            2014-03-10    70             1205         2014-03-05    75
```

I've know how to get all of the previous Table B rows joined to the Table A rows by using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and filtering by date in the WHERE clause, and I know how to get the Top row from Table B, but I haven't been able to work out how to get the top child record that occurs before the date of the record in Table A. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using OUTER APPLY in T-SQL.

For each record in TableA, we're looking for a record in TableB for the same user but with a test date prior to the test date in TableA and we're also ordering the test in TableB to ensure we're getting the most recent test from TableB (but still prior to the test date from TableA).

```
SELECT
    A.[UserID],
    A.[TestID] [TestA_ID],
    A.[TestDate] [TestADate],
    A.[Score] [TestAScore],
    B.[TestB_ID],
    B.[TestBDate],
    B.[TestBScore]
FROM [TableA] A
OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            B1.[TestID] [TestB_ID],
            B1.[TestDate] [TestBDate],
            B1.[Score] [TestBScore]
        FROM [TableB] B1
        WHERE   A.[UserID] = B1.[UserID]
            AND A.[TestDate] > B1.[TestDate]
        ORDER BY 
            B1.[TestDate] DESC
    ) B
```

Or another option might be to use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to find the record from TableB. I have a hunch this one wouldn't perform as well because it needs to hit TableA twice, but can't be sure without running tests.

```
SELECT
    A.[UserID],
    A.[TestID] [TestA_ID],
    A.[TestDate] [TestADate],
    A.[Score] [TestAScore],
    B.[TestB_ID],
    B.[TestBDate],
    B.[TestBScore]
FROM [TableA] A
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[UserID], A.[TestID] ORDER BY B.[TestDate] DESC) [rn],
            A.[UserID],
            A.[TestID] [TestA_ID],
            B.[TestID] [TestB_ID],
            B.[TestDate] [TestBDate],
            B.[Score] [TestBScore]
        FROM [TableA] A
        INNER JOIN [TableB] B
        ON      A.[UserID] = B.[UserID]
            AND A.[TestDate] > B.[TestDate]
    ) B
ON      A.[UserID] = B.[UserID]
    AND A.[TestID] = B.[TestA_ID]
    AND B.[rn] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but your query winds up with a result set other than what I am looking for. I need the data from every record in TableA joined to the data from the top child record in TableB with a test date previous to the test date in TableA.

Comment: Using the sample data you provided, this code returns exactly what you provided as a desired output. Could you please update your post to include a scenario where this code doesn't work so I can adjust the code to meet your needs?

Comment: Eilert, thanks for the reply. I'm getting didfferent results with your code. The fourth row returned by your code:


`103 4 2014-03-10 70 NULL NULL NULL`

I will try to update the example to make it clearer what I want. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if this is doing what you need it to.

Comment: Eilert, thank you very much. The outer apply solution works great. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help. Now I just need to wrap my head around Apply.

Comment: Cool, it took me a lot of fiddling with APPLY before I really understood it. But it's great to have in your toolbox once you figure out how to use it. Not to be vain or anything, but I think it is customary to upvote when you mark something as an answer :)

Comment: I tried upvoting when I marked it, but it says that I don't have enough reputation points yet.